# Vine like navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ui-design

So I'm looking for a library that accomplish the same navigation controller of the vine app. For those who don't know what I mean here you go:

[image: vine nc]

So basically it should replace my tabbarcontroller. Is there some similar out there?

If not how can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this samples.
DropdownMenu , REMenu

https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu

https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu

Comment: Well what should I say. Nailed it!